# Does anyone have experience with a lemon tree as an indoor bonsai?

Tags: bonsai, lemons

I grew a "tree" out of a lemon seed. As I'm not living in a climate for lemon trees I'm trying to make an indoor bonsai out of it. I'm not sure if it is good bonsai material. Will it build enough bark? Can I get the leaves small enough for a bonsai? Any experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this for a few years with a seedling.  The trunk will change from green to gray bark when it gets about the diameter of a small straw. The leaves will reduce in size but not in a proportion that is suitable for a small bonsai of less than a foot tall.
I found pictures where it seemed to be more suitable for a large bonsai of two to three feet tall.  At that size the thorns and leaves are more in proportion to the trunk.

Soil composition is essential for success as [this question about lemon trees](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/how-should-a-lemon-tree-with-yellowing-leaves-peeling-bark-and-small-fruit-be) shows. For a bonsai I favour a watering wick so the plant has ready access to water but is never soggy. One or two days of inattention when it's hot and years of work can be compromised.